# Prove that $\measuredangle AQP+\measuredangle NAP=90^o$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Let a triangle $ABC$ be right at $A$, $AH$ be the altitude to the side $BC$. Let $M$ be an arbitrary point located in $AH$. Draw circle $B$ with the radius $BA$, circle $C$ with the radius $CA$. The circle $B$ and the circle $C$ respectively cut $CM, BM$ at $P$ and $Q$. Circle $(HPQ)$ cut $BC$ at $N$. Prove that $$\measuredangle AQP+\measuredangle NAP=90^o$$

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3witcblkct30o1/VG.ggb?dl=0) is the GeoGebra file of this image.
[image]

Comment: You write "the cicle $B$ and the circle $C$ respectively cut $CM$, $PM$ at $P$ and $Q$". Do you mean "the ci[r]cle $B$ and the circle $C$ respectively cut $CM$, [$BM$] at $P$ and $Q$"? Also, your diagram makes it hard to see the label for point $H$, and to a lesser extent some of the other point labels.

Answer (score 2):

The following works only for the particular case when the circle PHNQ passes through A too.

$\alpha + \gamma = \beta + \gamma$ (angles in the same segment)

$= \delta$ (exterior angles cyclic quad)

$= 90^0$!

[figure-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8WhS.png)

For the general case, I have to give up after a long period of trial. However, I would like to share some of the interesting findings that might be useful for those who are interested.

(1) Some colored pairs of lines are parallel. XY should be parallel to PB’ too but that remains to be proven.

(2) PP’A’M’ is cyclic.

(3) If Point T is the perpendicular point of XTY and APTP’, then the question is solved.

[image]

Comment: +1, though it would be more clear to place angle $\delta$ on the other side of line segment $\overline{AH}$, since $\delta$ and $\alpha+\beta$ would then be opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral, which are supplementary. This just uses a more well-known theorem than your argument does.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Though it is more well-know, it takes one more step.

Comment: True.~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: But the point $A$ is not necessarily on the circle $PHQ$
and $\angle NQA\ne90$ for many points $M\in AH$.

Comment: @g.kov  The OP has the picture changed after I posted my answer. Now I have to figure out a whole new problem.

Comment: @Mick Sorry for the misleading diagram. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @DDK No harm done. It is a new challenge that all.

Comment: @g.kov FYI: A new solution for the general case has been posted.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is complicated (and I hope someone can provide a simpler one). It will be subdivided into several parts. In addition, lots of constructions are needed and therefore written descriptions will all be omitted. I hope that the picture can clearly show how the new or extended lines are drawn and the intersection points are located.

[image]

In particular, $C’R$ is produced to cut $AB’$ at $T$. By angles in the same segment, all green-marked angles are all equal to $c$. This means that $C’T // SB’, \measuredangle ARC’ = 90^{\circ}$ and $\measuredangle ATC’ =\measuredangle AB’S$.

The circum-circle $AC’T$ is created (with $C’T$ as diameter). It can be shown that $\measuredangle AC’T = \measuredangle ATC’ = 45^{\circ}$.

We then add a few more lines to obtain the following diagram (pls ignore the red and blue circles):-

[image]

To get the required, it is sufficient to show that $\measuredangle AXR = 90^{\circ}$. Before that, we need a lemma with the following assumptions:-

1. Let $A$ be one of the endpoints of the common chord ($AC’$) of two intersecting circles.
2. Let $\phi$ be the angle between the tangents (at the same point to the two circles) through $A$.
3. Through $A$, a line is drawn cutting the two circles at $J$ and $K$.

[image]

Conclusion:- $\measuredangle JC’K = \phi$ . [The proof is via “angles in alternate segment”.] This fact will be used for $\phi = 45^{\circ}$; (using the same diagram).

That fact will be used again for $\phi = 90^{\circ}$. (See the diagram below.)

[image]

Incorporating everything, we finally have the following picture:-

[image]

From which, we find that $DR // EA$ because $\lambda = \mu = 45^0$

$\measuredangle AXR = 90^{\circ}$ because $DR // EA$ and $\measuredangle EAX = 90^{\circ}$.

Comment: Thanks for all your helps, @Mick. I had a solution of this problem from a friend of mine. And it seems simplier than your answer. Would you mind if I post it. :)

Comment: Certainly no. You are welcome to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a solution of one of my friends.**

[File GeoGebra](https://www.dropbox.com/s/62z4e9j21vtycvj/AQP.ggb?dl=0) of this image.

We will have a coloful diagram :D
[image]

OK, at first, let $CP$ cut circle $(B)$ at $P'$, $BQ$ cut $(C)$ at $Q'$  ($P′\not\equiv P;Q′\not\equiv Q$);

$(B)$ cut $\left(C\right)$ at the 2nd point $D\implies H$ is midpoint of $AD$

We obtain $(CMPP')=(BMQQ')=-1$ (The sign of [Harmonic Range](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicRange.html))

$\implies BC, PQ, P'Q'$ meet in the same point $J$

The line through $B$ which is parallel to $AD$ cut $Q'D$ at $Q_1$, do analog thing we determine the point $P_1$.

According to Menelaus theorem we have: $\displaystyle\frac{JB}{JC}=\frac{P'M}{P'C}.\frac{Q'B}{Q'M}=\frac{DM}{CP_{1}}.\frac{BQ_{1}}{DM}=\frac{BQ_{1}}{CP_{1}}$

We will prove that $J$ be ray center of $(B)$ and $\left(C\right)\quad  (*)$

Indeed: 
\begin{align*}
(*)\displaystyle & \iff \frac{BQ_{1}}{CP_{1}}=\frac{BD}{CD}\\
&\iff \frac{\sin \angle{BDQ_{1}}}{\sin \angle{Q_{1}}}=\frac{\sin \angle{CDP_{1}}}{\sin \angle{P_{1}}}\\
&\iff \frac{\sin \angle{DAQ'}}{\sin \angle{ADQ'}}=\frac{\sin \angle{DAP'}}{\sin \angle{ADP'}}\\
&\iff \frac{DQ'}{AQ'}=\frac{DP'}{AP'}\left (=\sqrt{\frac{MD}{MA}}  \right ) \text{( True )}
\end{align*}

Hence we obtain $(*)$ true.

We obtain : $\overline{MP}.\overline{MP'}=\overline{MQ}.\overline{MQ'}\implies P, Q,P',Q'$ will be at the same circle.

Hence, we implies $\overline{JA}^{2}=\overline{JP'}.\overline{JQ'}=\overline{JP}.\overline{JQ}=\overline{JH}.\overline{JN}$

---

Now, we use the equivalent change (This will use the result of IMO 2012)

We have : \begin{align*}
 &\angle AQP+\angle NAP=90^{\circ}\\
\iff &90^{\circ}-\angle AQP=\angle NAP=\angle QAP-\angle QAN\\
\iff &180^{\circ}-2\angle AQP=2\angle QAP-2\angle QAN\\
\iff &(180^{\circ}-\angle QAP-\angle AQP)-\angle AQP=\angle QAP-2\angle QAN\\
\iff &\angle APQ-\angle AQP=\angle NAP-\angle NAQ\color{red}{\quad(2)}
\end{align*}

Let $E$ be intersection point of $BP$ and $CQ$. We know that $EP+EQ$ (IMO 2012), $\implies \angle EQP=\angle EPQ$.

Hence \begin{align*}
 (2)&\iff\angle APQ-\angle NAP=\angle AQP-\angle NAQ\\
&\iff\angle APQ+ \angle EPQ -\angle NAP=\angle AQP+\angle EQP-\angle NAQ\\
&\iff\angle CAN=\angle BAN\quad\color{red}{(3)}
\end{align*}

---

**Solution 1**

We obtain $JA\perp AN$

But from $(*)$ we obtain $AJ$ be the external bisector of $\angle A$ of $\triangle ABC$

Hence, $AN$ be the internal bisector of of $\angle A$ of $\triangle ABC$

$\implies $ OK.

---

**Solution 2**

We easily have $JA\perp AN$, and $\triangle JAQ$ is uniforms with $\triangle JPA$
\begin{align*}
&\implies \angle APQ=\angle JAQ\\
&\iff \angle APQ +\angle NAQ =90^{\circ }\\
&\iff\angle AQP +\angle NAP =90^{\circ } 
\end{align*}

Q.E.D

Comment: Received. Takes time to study. Will response later.

Comment: (1) In the figure, M and Q are a bit away from their should-be positions. (2) Though I don’t quite understand the meaning of (CMPP’) = … = –1, I suspect that there must be a typo because “BC, PC, …” are 2 different lines and if they intersect at C, then they will never meet again at J. (3) the fact that “$\angle CAN = \angle BAN = 45^0$” has been implied in some of my diagrams. (4) Your JA coincides with my purple line (t) which is parallel to other purple lines (all making a $45^0$) with AB extended and are perpendicular to AN extended. .

Comment: @Mick, I had fixed this solution. Can you check it?

Comment: (1) Good for learning something new – “the harmonic range”. (2) As mentioned in my earlier comment that “$∠CAN=∠BAN=45^0$” has been found in an earlier stage by an easier method. (3) Your friend’s solution is concise but not simpler. The fact that my work seems to be longer is because I expand it by including 2 lemmas (which, of course, can just be simply stated). (4) This is a nice question. While solving it, I found more than 20 useful and interesting facts. Every one of them can independently be set as a standalone question.